# Using Cron to Reboot

Tags: linux, cron

I'm using a Raspberry Pi for a status display, but for whatever reason it gets incredabbly sluggish after a day or so of running so I wanted to reboot it every day so I setup a cron job to do that every morning at 8:50. But, it doesn't seem to be working. Is there anything special about using cron to do a reboot?

This is my crontab for the `root` user:

```
# m   h  dom mon dow   command
50    8   *   *   *     shutdown now -r >> /var/log/cron.log
0,30  *   *   *   *     date >> /var/log/cron.log
```

The second line works just fine, but I can't seem to get the restart command to work. It doesn't even output anything to the log.

Comment: You need to execute `shutdown` and `reboot` as root.

Comment: Try to find out why your status display application is becoming sluggish.

Comment: Ken, that is the root's crontab. 

Basile, I know and I will figure it out eventually but we've got bigger fish to fry right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the fully specified path to shutdown.  date may be in the PATH in roots cron environment, /sbin may not be looked up.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. I'm kinda curious why it wouldn't have given me an error message.

Comment: It probably did ... you're only redirecting STDOUT to your log; STDERR is most likely in root's mail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the root user crontab

```
sudo crontab -e
```

then..

```
50 8 * * * reboot
```

Save and exit.